# 2X2 LED troffer with battery backup - wiring question(s)

Tags: light-fixture, led, recessed-lighting

Looked around and saw similar questions, but not quite what I need.  I am replacing a 2X2 fluorescent fixture in my basement with an LED unit (Cree FP22-34L-40K-10V-EB14, install manual at https://www.e-conolight.com/media/productdocuments/document/file/e/s/essentia_install_fp14_fp22_fp24_series.pdf, and wiring diagram is page 3).  I didn't realzie it when I got it, but this one has a battery backup.  The old one connected to a switch on the wall, so it only has switched voltage.  After spending some quality time with a meter and some tape for marking wires, I have found and labeled the hot and neutral coming into the box.  I have a handful of other wires going through the box to power the other two lights on the other side of the basement.  Looking at the wiring diagram, and thinking this through, I am pretty sure I just need to pigtail the hot from the panel to both the hot and switched hot of the new fixture.  The neutrals can all go back the way they were, and the only thing added is the pigtail for the unswitched hot.  I am hoping someone can look at the wiring diagram and confirm that I am thinking this through correctly.  Thanks!!

Comment: The manual you linked does not seem to mention a backup battery...

Comment: Well, fudge.  I should have checked it first.  I can't find it online for this fixture (one linked on the page is for the standard fixture, I asked Cree to post the correct manual).  I added a photo to my OneDrive - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvE5CcGPIhilg-JO2ZqHxLDb1dsDnw?e=19PcVA  Thanks for checking this out!

Comment: It appears I cannot yet add a photo, so I had to include the link.  Basically there are 2 hot leads to the driver, switched hot and unswitched hot.  The switched hot comes off the unswitched hot to the driver itself.

Comment: The link is fine, *as long as it's **the right** link*. The troffer you have linked to does not have a battery backup: it has 0-10V dimming.  Please validate your link.  Does your actual troffer have a purple and gray wire coming out of it?

Comment: I added a link above to my OneDrive that shows the wiring diagram.  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvE5CcGPIhilg-JO2ZqHxLDb1dsDnw?e=19PcVA  The documentation on the web site of the retailer that I originally linked is incorrect for the product.  I only made sure I was on the right page.  I did not check the accuracy of the PDF itself.  I have the purple and gray for a dimmer, but I am not using a dimmer.  I have a switched hot, an unswitched hot, and a neutral.

Comment: This is the troffer I purchased.  https://www.e-conolight.com/cree-lighting-essentia-led-2x2-flat-lens-troffer-fp22-series-battery-backup-white.html

Comment: @JoePhillips -- re: adding a photo.  You can click the [edit] link in "share edit..." under the bottom left of your post and then use the button that looks like a stylized mountain-and-sun painting to add pictures.

Comment: Lets see if I can attach the diagram.  Nope.  I think I don't have enough points yet.

Comment: Yeah, we’re having a heck of a time with drawings!  I’ll shoop and insert Your scan tonight.  Does this thing really have 8 wires plus a red loop coming out of it?

Comment: It Yeah, it is a mess.  I was in it again last night and figured out more of the wiring.  I have a hot/neutral from the wall switch, hot/neutral from the panel, hot/neutral in a whip to the fixture, and a hot/neutral to the rest of the fixtures.  I think the red in there is for the hardwired smoke detectors.  I am just leaving that one alone.  Looking at the before photo, I thought that the hot from the panel tied to the neutral of the switch, so I wired it that way and put the rest under nuts per color.  The light does not turn on/off, but the switch for this light now controls the others...

Comment: This switch now controls the other fixtures on the circuit.  So, I am going to try connecting the neutral from the panel to the hot of the switch, since that is (I think) the only other option that makes sense (feed the rest of the fixtures, etc.).  Once I have that figured out, I _should_ be able to pigtail the switched and unswitched hot from the panel feed to the fixture.  I think.  Maybe not, though.  Still trying to understand.  May just buy another fixture without the battery backup.

Comment: Rewired juction box.  Neutral from switch tied to hot from panel  hot from switch tied to rest of hot.  This switch still controls the other fixtures.  I am at a loss.

Comment: The old fixture is not part of the circuit...  starting again from scratch.

Comment: Can you post photos of the box + fixture wiring please?

Comment: On my OneDrive.  I can't add photos to my posts.  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvE5CcGPIhilg-JO2ZqHxLDb1dsDnw?e=6IkyG6

Comment: @JoePhillips -- can you not [edit] your post and use the "mountain and sun" button on the editor toolbar to add photos?

Comment: I’m not seeing that toolbar  I’m guessing it is because I’m still fresh. I’ll post the link to the wiring diagram later. Manufacturer just added it to the product page v

Comment: Link to correct manual (diagram on page 3) - https://www.e-conolight.com/media/productdocuments/document/file/e/s/essentia_install_fp14-eb_fp22-eb_fp24-eb_series.pdf  I think I figured it out.  I need to have a third wire from the fixture to the switch.  There is currently only 2 wires.  I am replacing the battery backup unit to one without battery backup.  Problem solved.

Comment: @JoePhillips -- reframe that into an answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Let me see if I did this right.  The solution is a 3rd wire to the light switch that can serve as the switched hot.  The current wiring uses the neutral (white wire) as the switched hot (and should be marked as such, typically a piece of black tape near each end) and the hot (black wire) as the unswitched hot.  The neutral wire in this scenario would be connected to the neutral at the box in the ceiling and capped at the switch location.

Comment: @JoePhillips I think the emphasis should be on that swapping the fixture was necessary to fix this; also, it's just a white wire, not a neutral, when it's used as a switched hot

Comment: Gotcha.  I am going to swap out the fixture later.  For now, I just put one in that is switched.